# Unity OnCollisionEnter not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I want to happen is when you run into a cube, the game resets, but this is not working. I can't even get it to log anything in the console when it collides. I have a rigidbody and a collider on both objects, but they still don't work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class collisionScript : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisonEnter(Collision hit)
{
    if (hit.collider.tag == ("Wall"))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("gameover");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made an error on method name, you call it `OnCollisonEnter()` while it should be `OnCollisionEnter()`. Unfortunately but correctly this kind of errors aren't reported by IDE because you may want to create a method with that name.

Answer (score 0):

You have it wrong written

It's `OnCollisionEnter`

Also:
- Check that the moving gameObject has a RigidBody component
- The object which is the wall has the tag "Wall"